# Connect to remote PostGreSql Server using Dask and Psycog2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, dask

I am able to connect to remote PostgreSQL server using pandas and psycopg2. Now, knwowing that pandas is slow to read databases, I thought that using Dask could solve this concern. So, I decided to run with Psycopg2 and Dask but I am receiving below error:

```
import psycopg2 as pg
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import pandas as pd
connection = pg.connect("host='xxx.x.x.x' dbname=xxxx user=xxxx password='xxxx' port = 'xxxx'")

df = dd.read_sql_table(table='xxxx', uri='postgresql+psycopg2://user_name:password@localhost:port_number/database_name', index_col='id', npartitions=20)

df.compute()

c:\users\user_name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\base.py:3323: SAWarning: Skipped unsupported reflection of expression-based index uc_table_name_lower_code
  "expression-based index %s" % idx_name
```

What the above error means? Even though I get error, it show the table dataframe.
How to run connection without getting error message?

Comment: It looks like a warning, not an error. Warnings are printed to stdout by default, but you can filter them out. https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

Comment: What means by: Skipped unsupported reflection of expression-based index uc_table_name_lower_code
  "expression-based index %s" % idx_name ?